# Talking about a third person, formally

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns, singular-they

I am talking about my professor to his secretary. Is it polite and formal to refer to him as "he"? or should I use "they"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it’s polite to refer to your professor as *he*. This is standard English.

If your professor has some pronouns that he prefers that people use when talking about him, surely the secretary will know and will so inform you.

Answer (score 2):

The "gender-neutral" use of *[singular] **they*** doesn't really work if the gender of the referent is explicitly known to both speaker and audience (or writer and readership).

So whereas it's fine to say *Your professor can assign whatever grade **they** like to your paper* if you don't know the gender of the addressee's professor, you can't really say ***My** professor can assign whatever grade **they** like* - except maybe in some unusual context where you don't [yet] know your professor's gender.

It's worth pointing out that gender-neutral ***they*** has been around in English for centuries. It's not particularly connected to concepts of formal / informal language, or male / female "social equality".

---

But arguably OP didn't really need to ask the question in the first place...

> Natural...
> *I am talking about my professor to **his** secretary. Is it polite and formal to address **him** as "he"? or should I use "they"?*

> Non-idiomatc...
> *I am talking about my professor to **their** secretary. Is it polite and formal to address **them** as "he"? or should I use "they"?*

Comment: He is talking to the secretary.  He would say: My professor, which you don't even mention.

Comment: @Lambie I take it that's a joke?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OP's question is clueless. First, he needs to be put right, then, you get into the other stuff. If a student is talking about his prof. to a sec't. then, he need only say He and his or She and her. The they thing here is too much. No need for it.

Comment: I'm sure this has been said before (use of 'singular they etc' when speaking of a person of known gender)... but the only 'duplicate' I could find I realised just in time wasn't a different thread.

Comment: "Lambie I'd say that OP's question is better asked elsewhere (say Interpersonal Skills), but it looks sincere to me. There _is_ the wider issue  (use of 'singular they etc' when speaking of a person of known gender [in a formal document, say]), but I'm sure this has been addressed here before.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Shouldn't the professor be **addressed** as *you*? I don't know about FumbleFingers, but I can't **address** people in the third person, only in the second person.

Comment: It is possible that the OP is a speaker of a language in which the plural would be used in such cases as a mark of respect, and that this is what is behind the question, rather than any concerns about gender neutrality. The question may have been apt on the learners' site.

Comment: @tchrist OED possibly has '[should] address X as' = '[should] refer to acceptably X as', but the latter is obviously safer.